# $E(x)= |x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-|x+3|+\dots+|x+2016|$. Find the minimum value of $E$.

Tags: calculus

Can any one help me finding the minimum value of the following expression:
$$
E(x)= |x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-|x+3|+\dots+|x+2016|
$$
where $x$ is a real number.

Comment: Have you seen what the graph looks like? Try with fewer terms (like three, or five), and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

**1) If $x \geq 0$:**

$E(x) = (|x| - |x+1|) + (|x+2| - |x+3|) + ... + (|x + 2014| - |x+2015|) + |x + 2016| = \frac{2016}{2}(|x| - |x+1|)  + |x + 2016|,$

since $\forall x \in [0, \infty) \hspace{.2cm} (|x| - |x+1|) = (|x+2| - |x+3|) = ... = (|x + 2014| - |x+2015|) = -1$.

I.e. $x \geq 0 \Rightarrow E(x) = 1008 \times (-1)+ |x + 2016| \Rightarrow\underset{x \in [0, \infty)} \min E(x) = E(0) = 1008.$

**2) If $ x \leq - 2015 $:**

$E(x) = (|x| - |x+1|) + (|x+2| - |x+3|) + ... + (|x + 2014| - |x+2015|) + |x + 2016| = \frac{2016}{2}(|x| - |x+1|) + |x + 2016|,$

$\forall x \in (-\infty, -2015] \hspace{.2cm} (|x| - |x+1|) = (|x+2| - |x+3|) = ... = (|x + 2014| - |x+2015|) = -1$.

I.e. $x \geq 0 \Rightarrow E(x) = 1008  + |x + 2016| \Rightarrow \underset{x \in (-\infty, -2015]} \min E(x) = E(-2016) = 1008.$

**3) If $- 2015 < x < 0$:**

$\forall n \in \{1,...,2016\} \hspace{.2cm} n+1 <|x| \Rightarrow |x + n| = |x| - n \wedge |x + n + 1| = |x| - n - 1$ I.e. $|x + n| - |x + n + 1| = 1. $ **(i)**

Following the same logic:

$\forall n \in \{1,...,2016\} \hspace{.2cm} n >|x| \Rightarrow |x + n| = n - |x|  \wedge |x + n + 1| =  n + 1 - |x|$ I.e. $|x + n| - |x + n + 1| = -1. $ **(ii)**

**3.1) If $- 2015 < x < 0 \wedge \lceil x \rceil$ - even:**

$ \lceil x \rceil := k$ $\Rightarrow x \in [k, k-1]$.

$\forall n < |k| \hspace{.2cm} k-even \Rightarrow n+1 < k. \hspace{.2cm}$  Here **(i)** implies $|x+n|−|x+n+1|=1.$ I.e there are $\frac{k}{2}$ terms in $E(x)$ that behave as in 2).

$n = k \hspace{.2cm} \Rightarrow |x+n| = |x| - k \wedge |x+ n + 1| = k + 1 - |x|.\hspace{.2cm}$  Here $ |x+n|−|x+n+1| = |x| - k - (k + 1 - |x|) = 2(|x| - k) - 1 =:r.\hspace{.2cm}$. $k - even \Rightarrow r \in [-1, 1).\hspace{.2cm}$ Compared to 2) this term is smaller.

$\forall n > |k| \hspace{.2cm} \wedge n-even \hspace{.2cm}$ **(ii)** applies. Thus here $|x+n|−|x+n+1|=-1.$ There are $1008 - 1- \frac{k}{2}$ terms in $E(x)$ that switch sign compared to 2).

Thus for **k - even** we have: $E(x) = \frac{k}{2} \times 1 + r + (1007- \frac{k}{2}) \times (-1) +|x+2016|= |x+2016| + k-1007+r = 2016 - k - (|x| - k) + k - 1007 + r = 1009 + \frac{r}{2} \geq 1008,$

where $|x| = k \Leftrightarrow E(x) = 1008.$

**3.2) If $- 2015 < x < 0 \wedge \lceil x \rceil$ - odd:**

$ n \leq k - 3 \hspace{.2cm} \wedge n-even \hspace{.2cm} \Rightarrow |x+n|−|x+n+1|=1 \hspace{.1cm}$ by **(i)**. Thus up to and including |x+(k-3)|−|x+(k-2)| all terms behave as in 2). There are a total of $\frac{k-1}{2}$ such terms.

$ n > k  \hspace{.2cm} \wedge n-even \hspace{.2cm} \Rightarrow |x+n|−|x+n+1|=-1 \hspace{.1cm}$ by **(ii)**. From and including |x+ k + 1|−|x+k+2| all terms change sign. There are a total of $1008 -  \frac{k+1}{2}$ such terms.

$ n = k-1 \Rightarrow \hspace{.1cm} |x+n| = |x+(k-1)| = |x| - (k-1) \wedge 
|x+n+1| = |x+k| = |x| - k \hspace{.1cm} \Rightarrow |x+n| - |x+(k-1)| = 1.$
Thus in total there are $1008 - \frac{k+1}{2}$ terms that switch sign compared to 2) and $\frac{k+1}{2}$ that don't.

Thus for **k - odd** we have: $E(x) = \frac{k+1}{2} \times 1 + (1008 - \frac{k+1}{2}) \times (-1) + |x + 2016| = 2016 -|x| - 1008 +  k+1 = 1009 - |x|+ k+1 = 1008 + k+1-|x| \geq 1009.$

I.e. $\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}\min E(x) = 1008. \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{argmin}}  E(x) = \{-2k| k \in \{0, ... 1008\}\}$

Comment: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |x| - |x+1|)= |x+2| - |x+3|$，take $x=-1/2$.

Comment: True, which means $ \forall x \in (-2016, 0) E(x) \neq 1008 + |2016 + x|$

Comment: @ Rieman I have corrected the proof and checked it for all nonpositive integers with R, would you please take a look?

Comment: Really Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the graph of $E(x)= |x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-|x+3|+\dots+|x+n|$, you can notice that if $n$ is even (our case), then the graph of $E(x)$ is symmetric to the line $x=-\frac{n}{2}$. In fact here the graph of $E(x)= |x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-|x+3|+|x+4|$:
[image]

To find the minimum value I have to set $x\geq0$, so: $$E(x)= |x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-|x+3|+\dots+|x+2016|=x-x-1+x+2-x-3+\dots+x+2016$$ Removing absolute values, I obtain: $2+4+\cdots+2016-(1+3+5+\cdots+2015)=A-B$. I have now two aritmetic series; their values are:$A=\frac{2016}{2}\cdot(4+1007\cdot2)=1008\cdot2018$ and $B=\frac{2016}{2}\cdot(2+1007\cdot2)=1008\cdot2016$.

Now I obtain: $A-B=1008\cdot2018-1008\cdot2016=1008\cdot2=2016$.

I hope it has helped you...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have one question, why you set x as positive to find the minimum?

Comment: In that way I have removed the absolute values; if not it would have been more complicated to continue.

Comment: X doesn't simplify away because E(x) has 2017 summands which all contain x (n goes from 0 to .2016).

Comment: Sorry, my error. The result doesn't change, anyway.

Comment: It does, it depends on x now.

Comment: As demonstrateted in the graph the result hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{align}E(x+2)&=|x+2|-|x+3|
\mp\cdots+|x+2016|-|x+2017|+|x+2018|\\&=E(x)-|x|+|x+1|-|x+2017|+|x+2018|\end{align} $$
and $$|x+1|-|x|=\begin{cases}1&x\ge 0\\-1&x\le -1\\2x+1&-1\le x\le0\end{cases} $$
$$|x+2017|-|x+2018|=\begin{cases}1&x\ge -2017\\-1&x\le -2018\\2(x+2017)+1&-2018\le x\le2017\end{cases} $$
From this, $$\tag1E(x+2)\le E(x) \qquad \text{for }x\le -1$$
$$\tag2E(x+2)\ge E(x) \qquad \text{for }x\ge -2017$$
so that the minimum of $E$ on the interval $[-2017,-1]$ (which exists because $E$ is continuous and the interval is compact) is also the global minimum of $E$. Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, 
$$\tag3E(x+2)= E(x) \qquad \text{for }-2017\le x\le -1$$
so that we can look for the minimum on any interval of length $2$ within $[-2017,-1]$, for example on $[-3,-1]$. There,
$$ E(x)=|x|-|x+1|+|x+2|-(x+3)+(x+4)\mp\cdots+(x+2016)=|x|-|x+1|+|x+2|+const$$
and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $f(x) = |x|-|x+1|$ we have

$$
E_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}f(x+2k)
$$

and

$$
-(n+1) \le E_n(x) \le n+1
$$